# Is there any library to query the whois database for domains information?

Tags: c#, dns

I'd like to write my own script in C# to test my own dictionary of too-many-to-do-it-manually words against whois database of world wide web domains.

Is there any free library / script that would allow my application to test the words against free domains and get the results quite quick?

There are Internet applications like whoix.com that allow me to test 25 domains, however I'd need a lot more.

If you got a possible solution, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/class.qpx?id=10) might do what you are looking for, it is only a basic query by domain but I would think that would be enough for what you are doing.